# Reshape and merge columes in R

Tags: r, merge, transpose

So i have a question of transpose data in R.
I have a set of data looking like the following:

```
 id startdate   enddate
 1  10/15/2008  .
 1  .           .
 1  .           .
 1  .           08/25/2009
 2  12/09/2008  .
 2  .           12/18/2008
```

I want to make the data look like

```
  id startdate  endend
  1  10/15/2008 08/25/2009
  2  12/09/2008 12/18/2008
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to do it??
Thank you very very much!!

Comment: Are the `.`s really in your data or are those actually filled in with different date values?

Comment: @MCheng: your feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>%
gather(Var, Val, startdate:enddate) %>% 
filter(Val!=".") %>% 
spread(Var,Val)

#   id  startdate    enddate
# 1  1 10/15/2008 08/25/2009
# 2  2 12/09/2008 12/18/2008
```

Or

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(subset( melt(dat, id.vars="id"), value!="."), id~variable, value.var="value")
#  id  startdate    enddate
#1  1 10/15/2008 08/25/2009
#2  2 12/09/2008 12/18/2008
```

In cases, where the number of entries per `id` for `startdate` and `enddate` differs. For example:

```
 dat[5,2] <- "."
 dcast(subset( melt(dat, id.vars="id"), value!="."), id~variable, value.var="value")
 #  id  startdate    enddate
 #1  1 10/15/2008 08/25/2009
 #2  2       <NA> 12/18/2008
```

#### data

```
 dat <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), startdate = c("10/15/2008", 
 ".", ".", ".", "12/09/2008", "."), enddate = c(".", ".", ".", 
 "08/25/2009", ".", "12/18/2008")), .Names = c("id", "startdate", 
 "enddate"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code using base R:

```
ss = ddf$startdate[ddf$startdate != '.']
ee = ddf$enddate[ddf$enddate != '.']
outdf = data.frame(id=unique(ddf$id), startdate=ss, enddate=ee)
outdf
  id  startdate    enddate
1  1 10/15/2008 08/25/2009
2  2 12/09/2008 12/18/2008
```

Data:

```
dput(ddf)
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), startdate = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c(".", "10/15/2008", "12/09/2008"
), class = "factor"), enddate = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
3L), .Label = c(".", "08/25/2009", "12/18/2008"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", 
"startdate", "enddate"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

ddf
  id  startdate    enddate
1  1 10/15/2008          .
2  1          .          .
3  1          .          .
4  1          . 08/25/2009
5  2 12/09/2008          .
6  2          . 12/18/2008
```